# Power BI comparative Bar Chart

Tags: powerbi, bar-chart, powerbi-desktop, stacked-bar-chart

I'm new to powerbi and need some help please!
I have a dataset of individuals, the age range they belong to and the state they live in.
Using Power BI, I created a Bar chart displaying the repartition of the individuals per age range.
Each bar sums the individuals of that age range regardless of the corresponding State, making it an information on the national scale.
I want to use a filter on the same barchart indicating the states. Once I do that, the old bars disappear and get replaced by the sum of the new applied filter. (If I choose New York and Ohio per say, each bar sums the count of individuals of the corresponding age range that live in New York and Ohio.)
Sample dataset: [sample dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeW3V.png)

What I want to achieve is for the initial bars to remain as they are upon adding filters (or slicers) and new bars get stacked side to side, one for each state per age range + the reference bar (the one of national scale) with legends indicating the selected states.
How can I achieve that?
Thank you!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)